# Como transformar em byte[] um arquivo carregado em um UploadFile C#

Tags: c#, blob

Antigamente eu conseguia pegar o caminho do arquivo pelo componente, porém agora depois de pesquisar sobre descobri que não é mais possível pegar o caminho do arquivo no cliente por questões de segurança etc. Em uma aplicação antiga eu tinha um método com este bloco de código abaixo, porém não é funcional atualmente com o UploadFile.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(caminhoArquivo, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        arquivo = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
    }
}
```

A questão é: Como fazer este procedimento de transformar um arquivo carregado por um UploadFile para Byte[].

---

Explicando melhor:

Eu estou usando este componente:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No primeiro código que eu postei reparem que o primeiro parâmetro para o Filestream é o "caminhoArquivo". O meu problema é que o componente FILEUPLOAD não me dá o caminho do arquivo! E eu gostaria de saber como farei esta conversão de arquivo pra byte[].

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer. Você está lendo o arquivo binário corretamente. Imagino que você esteja falando do `WebClient.UploadFile`, ele é usado para enviar um arquivo, não para receber.

Comment: Este método está correto, porém o caminhoArquivo nós não conseguimos pegar pelo UploadFile mais... Ai se eu rodar esse método pegando o (UploadFile.PostedFile.FileName) ele da NotFound. Entendeu agora?

Comment: Mas qual é a dúvida?

Comment: O método que o UploadFile tem pra pegar informações sobre o arquivo é este (UploadFile.PostedFile.FileName), porém ele só trás o nome + extensão do arquivo. Ai da notFound... esse é o meu problema.

Comment: Mostre como está usando isto.

Comment: @bigown Atualizei o tópico explicando melhor.

Answer (score 2):

A forma como estava fazendo, pegando o caminho do arquivo e depois abrindo um Stream desse caminho daria problema ao publicar a aplicação em um servidor, na sua maquina local iria funcionar já que o servidor e cliente seria na mesma maquina e o arquivo esta na mesma maquina, mas em um servidor em uma maquina separada, não iria encontrar o arquivo.

O componente FileUpload já contém o arquivo em si, não é preciso "carrega=lo" novamente.

Você pode fazer como [essa resposta do Tech Jerk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3082505/2358209).

Depois de criar o método que ele coloca na resposta:

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[input.Length];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Você chama no seu método no postback dessa maneira:

```
byte[] arquivo = ReadFully(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
```

Lembre de verificar antes de possui mesmo o arquivo, se o stream não é nulo e outras validações ;)

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se foi uma leitura apressada, mas eu não entendi exatamente a sua pergunta. De todo o modo, estou enviando abaixo a forma com que eu trabalho com upload de arquivos. Meus sistemas são em MVC, porém é fácil 'converter' o código abaixo.

**Classe que recebe arquivo**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), ValidateInput(false)]
    public JsonResult UploadArquivo()
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0] as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var ftp = new Helpers.Ftp();
            string nome = ftp.GerarNome(file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf(".")));
            if (ftp.UploadArquivo(file, nome, "Web/arquivos/"))
                return Json(new { Nome = nome }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            else
                return Json(new { Nome = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(new { Nome = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Definição do UploadArquivo**

```
public Boolean UploadArquivo(HttpPostedFileBase file, string nome, string diretorio)
    {

        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp+diretorio + nome);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, senha);
            request.UsePassive = false;

            request.Proxy = null;

            byte[] fileContents = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Position = 0;
            file.InputStream.Read(fileContents, 0, file.ContentLength);
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            response.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Definição do Ftp**

```
 private string ftp;
    private string usuario;
    private string senha;

    public Ftp()
    {
        ftp = "";
        usuario = "";
        senha = "";
    }
```

**Gerador de nome de arquivo**

```
 public string GerarNome(string extensao)
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(":", "").Replace("/", "").Replace(" ", "") + extensao;
        }
```

Com esse código você consegue tratar todo o processo de upload.
No caso, todas as classes com exceção ao `JsonResult UploadArquivo()` estão dentro de:

```
namespace Ui.Web.Helpers
{
    public class Ftp{
// Código
}
}
```

Não sei se a resposta ajudou, se você editar a sua pergunta com maiores instruções. Edito a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se ajuda:

```
byte[] byteArray = null;
using(var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
   f.PostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
   byteArray = ms.ToArray();
}
```